# In Hack, what are these called/how do they work: <<something>> over methods or classes?

Tags: hacklang

At first glance I thought they were decorators/annotations, but I'm not sure that's exactly what they are.

Comment: Something like `<<ClassOwner("Joel Marcey"), Description("This class does nothing")>>`? The documentation calls them *Attributes*.

Comment: https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/attributes/introduction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are called [attributes](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/attributes/introduction). Most of them have no inherent meaning, though a handful (`__Override`, `__ConsistentConstruct`, `__Memoize`, `__Deprecated`) have runtime and type checker meanings.